# Where can i find record for transactions/transfer made using smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I might be missing something obvious here, but where can i find the records/ receipts for transactions made using *transfer()* method in smart contract? Without using events or something explicit for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Events and receipts are not saved part of the contract. However they are saved part of the blockchain. Once they are generated they become part of the blockchain forever.

If you don't specifically save something in the contract storage you have to use the events and receipts to get data about the transactions.

Comment: So you are saying without making an explicit utility/event there is no way to know about the ether transfers from smart contract ? Doesn't that seems a bit odd for a completely transparent, decentralized technology if can't trace back a certain type ether transfers.

Comment: As long as the information is available and accessible it is transparent. That doesn't mean all tools exists to explore all the data possibilities user wants

Answer (score 0):

by knowing the address of a smart contract on the chain you can check it out on etherscan. [Here's an example](https://etherscan.io/address/0x888666CA69E0f178DED6D75b5726Cee99A87D698)

Comment: i don't think you understood my query. Please correct me if i'm wrong but I think list on that page shows the transactions from other accounts to contract or just calling a function of contract and i can also get these by _getTransaction()_  with a filter on *to* .